# Simple console I/O with async.js fails

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, callback

I am doing a simple exercise to understand how async.js works with node.js. The program will ask for hours worked and hourly rate and multiply them to tell the total income.

The code looks like this:

```
var async =require('async');
var rl = require('readline');

//variables
var horas=0;
var rate =0;
var sueldo =0;

//readline
var int=rl.createInterface({
    input:process.stdin,
    output:process.stdout
});

var items = [
    {nombre: "worked hours", valor:horas},
    {nombre:"hourly rate",valor:rate}
];

async.each(items,
      function(item,callback)
      {
          int.question('Tell me your '+ item.nombre,function(data) 
                                                    { 
                                                        item.valor =Number(data);
                                                        callback(null);
                                                    });
      },
      function(err,results){
          console.log(results);
      });
```

I know this same thing can be achieved using realine.question(), but the point of the exercise is to understand how async.js works.

When I run this code, only the first item in the collection gets called. No matter how many times I press Enter, the second item in the items array never gets processed. I think I am missing something very basic here but have no idea what. Can someone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [`async.eachSeries`](https://github.com/caolan/async#eachseriesarr-iterator-callback) instead of `async.each` here because you want the questions to occur one after the other instead of at the same time:

```
async.eachSeries(items, function(item,callback) { ... }
```

Comment: After using async.eachSeries, it behaves as I expected and both questions occurr one at a time. However, the final callback's arguments are undefined. Unless I misunderstood, I am supposed to recieve a results array in that callback, right? But both "err" and "results" come back undefined. It still works, because I am stuffing my values in the items array, but it would be nice to know how I can get at the results "the proper way".

Comment: @user1043793 Not with `each` or `eachSeries`, no.  The docs for those only list an `err` parameter to the final callback.  You may be thinking of `series` and `parallel`.